# How do I find the number of lines in an output in Linux?

Tags: linux, encoding

I have a text file of list of students with Marks and I want to find how many of them secured more than 80 in Maths. What should be the Linux command to do this? I used:

```
awk '{ if($2 > 80) print $0;}' Marks.txt
```

to print all such entries. But now I need to print their number directly. I am facing trouble in initializing count variable and then count = count + 1.

The text file is here:

```
#name maths phy
Manila 78 29
Shikhar 49 78
Vandana 65 87
Priyansh 75 22
Bina 52 69
Chitransh 98 93
William 88 73
Kaushal 38 85
Dilruba 65 94
Lalremruata 34 45
Qasim 58 62
Nitya 81 89
Jennita 96 91
Shobha 71 63
Talim 77 88
```

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my other answer, you can just add `wc -l` after the command:

```
awk '{ if($2 > 80) print $0;}' Marks.txt | wc -l
```

Comment: It is giving incorrect answer. I used :                                                                                                  awk '{ if($2 > 80) print $0;}' Marks.txt | wc -l
awk '{ if($3 > 80) print $0;}' Marks.txt | wc -l
awk '{ if($2 > 80 && $3>80) print $0;}' Marks.txt | wc -l              and it gives output as 5,8 and 4 respectively.